# How to retrieve value from Observable in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am failing in retrieving data from Observable.

I can't find where the problem is. As far as I understand my code is correct.

```
private IsPrivateLocation(id: string):boolean
{
    this.service.isLocationPrivate(id).subscribe(res => {
        this.location = res;
     });
     return this.location.isPrivate;
}
```

`this.location` is still `UNDEFINED` after method call. This is service method:

```
public isLocationPrivate(id:string):Observable<Location>
{
    return this.http.post(AppConfig.azurefunc.locationUri, {
        id: id,
        operatorId: AppConfig.user.operatorId
    }).pipe(map(res =>res.json()));
}
```

Why does it still undefined? What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
I managed to find a workaround without waiting for observable. However, I tried all the things that were offered below and none of them worked. Maybe that has something to do with the fact that I'm using Angular2 beta.

Comment: Can you post code showing how you use the method?

Comment: Do you mean how I call IsPrivateLocation() method? Something like var isPrivate=IsPrivateLocation(id);

Comment: Basically, the line `return this.location.isPrivate;` is executed _before_ `this.location = res;` - the former runs in the same event clock tick, and the latter after the HTTP call goes out and response is received.

Comment: I see that Observable doesn't fit me in my situation. I need to get the isPrivate value NOT asynchronously. I need to wait for it and only then go further. Is there way to return a Location, not an Observable<Location> from service's method?

Comment: Can you show us your workaround (you can just post it as an answer)?

Answer (score 1):

It's expected that it's `undefined`. As `Observables` are asynchronous. You should return an `Observable` from your `IsPrivateLocation()` method and then subscribe to it at the end of your chain.

Comment: I tried to do so and I got the same result. is there any way that I can return boolean from service's method? Something like .toPromise()?

Comment: `toPromise()` is also async, it won't make any difference. Show please what you tried that didn't work

Comment: I'll edit the question right now. Is there any way of returning `Location` from service's method `isLocationPrivate`, not an `Observable<Location>`?

Comment: I see that Observable doesn't fit me in my situation. I need to get the isPrivate value NOT asynchronously. I need to wait for it and only then go further. Is there way to return a Location, not an Observable<Location> from service's method?

Answer (score 0):

The Observable does not work like that,

```js
private LoadLocationPrivate(id:string){
 this.service.isLocationPrivate(id).subscribe(res => {
        this.location = res; 
        if(this.location.isPrivate){
           // Do something
        }else{
            // Do other thing
        }
     });
}
```

Call LoadLocationPrivate when you need to navigate.

Hope this helps

Comment: The problem is that I don't need to bind it to a view. I need the value because if it's true, then I'll redirect to another component.

Comment: So you can move the code use to navigate into subscribe callback

Comment: Could you please show how to do it? I'm completely unfamiliar to typescript but I need to make some changes on front-end of our system. That's why I'm struggling with it.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, an Observable can be either synchronous or asynchronous.
In your case the its asynchronous since you are using a http rest service.

Your option here ist to use **async/await**:

```
private async isPrivateLocation(id: string)
{
    const location = await this.service.isLocationPrivate(id);
    return this.location.isPrivate;
}
```

and to call the function:

```
const isPrivate = await this.isPrivateLocation(123);
```

(Of course this code may have some errors). Please see the docs for reference.
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

The other option would be to subscribe to the Observable and redirect in the callback, but from what I understand, it is not what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, what is `cost`? And regarding `isPrivateLocation` in your case: location is observable in this case and it doesn't have `isPrivate` property.

Comment: My mistake, "const" and not "cost". Have a look in the documentation: await is used to resolve the Promise / Observable

Comment: I've read it and tried it. Even if I use `await` location still has the type Observable<Location>, not just a Location. Thus, it doesn't have a property isPrivate.

Comment: Could you try: const isPrivate = await this.isPrivateLocation(123).toPromise();

Comment: Then my function needs to return Promise<Location>, and then I don't know what to do with Promise<...> object.

Comment: Nope, your function still returns Observable<Location>, with "toPromise" you can convert it to Promise (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html)